# Using go get with custom ports

Tags: go

I am developing modules stored on a private gitlab repo which uses a non default port. This means that if I want to import the module I would have to run the following command:

```
go get -u fake.ddns.net:99/something/something.git
```

Of course the name are fake but the situation is real. When I do this, I get an error on the illegal character : and if I remove the port specifier, the go get does not work.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If using git clone is the only option, it pretty disappointing. I hope they get around to do handle this situation better.

Comment: It's not the only option. Not sure why you think it is.

Comment: IT felt from the comment given

Comment: Which comment are you referring to?

Comment: in the link question. Anyhow, I found a way around based on it. So I should close the question and thanks for pointing out that other thread.

Comment: The linked question provides two answers.